# Javascript : Get button click in differents .js files

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

So in html i have a basic button, and 2 js files ( using module for import / export )

```
<head>
   <script defer type="module" src="js/file1.js"></script>
   <script defer type="module" src="js/file2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <button>Click me</button>
</body>
```

In the **file1.js**, i have something simple

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");

const handleClick = () => { 
  //do stuff
}

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

But i would like to also detect when this button is pressed in the **file2.js** to run different code.

After somes search ( unless i missed how to word it ) i've saw nothing.
And came up with a "solution" of declaring another click eventlistener in **file2.js**.
But it kind bother me having the button have 2 time the same eventListener..

Is there any better solution for what i'am looking to do ?

thanks !

Tried to declare again click EventListener in the file2.js to also, in this file monitor the click.

Comment: What's wrong with having two event listeners?

Comment: Export a function from file2 (with "different code"), import in file1 and call it on button click?

Comment: I was assuming it wasn't this good "performance" related to declare X time a same event on the same element, to monitor that across several files.

@Bqardi, oh true, i also can do that ! i was stuck in the idea of getting the "click event" in the second files, didnt thought of something simpler like that.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're trying to do is access your handleClick function in multiple files.

If so, you can do something like the following:

**File1.js**

```
//export handleClick function from File1.js
export function handleClick() { 
  //do stuff
}
```

**File2.js**

```
//import handleClick function from File1.js
import {handleClick} from './File1.js';

const button = document.querySelector("button");

//use the handleClick function you exported from File1.js
button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

You can continue using the function you exported from File1.js in multiple files by importing it the same way. Just make sure you have the correct file path for the import.

Comment: True, its also a good solutions like Bqardi was suggestion above, guess i was stuck in the idea of "spreading" the click event across several files that i didnt thought about something simpler 

Thanks for the answer !